# preg_match for several patterns

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing an app in PHP that needs to test a field for a proper voucher code.  The voucher entry can be in one of three patterns.  I'm no good at expressions, so was hoping for a little help from some of the experts here.

The three patterns are:
1000150000  (any 10 digits)
12345678   (any 8 digits)
3JFK-TAB-CDEFG (First spot a number, the rest alpha.  With or without hyphens)

I'm thinking, because the three voucher entries are so different, it might have to be done in three different IF statements.

Thanks for any/all help!!!
Rick

Comment: I'm no Regex expert, but I would assume that one big Regex that covers the 3 patterns would accomplish the same as having 3 different validations. With that said, I would personally separate into 3 different validations for better readability and code modularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
(^\d{10}$|^\d{8}$|^\d[A-Za-z-]+$)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/uI9dU0

Comment: So, something like: if(!preg_match("^\d{10}$|^\d{8}$|^\d[A-Za-z-]+$", $voucher)) { echo "NO MATCH"; }?

Comment: @Rick, Yes exactly. That's it.  :)

Comment: One more question.  It seems that the third match in the example above will work with any length string.  How would I modify it to only match on 12 or 14 character lengths?  14 with hyphens or 12 without.

Comment: @Rick, `(^\d{10}$|^\d{8}$|^\d[A-Za-z-]{13}$|^\d[A-Za-z]{11}$)`

Comment: @Rick, In your first comment on this answer, you ask, "something like: if(!preg_match("^\d{10}$|^\d{8}$|^\d[A-Za-z-]+$", $voucher))...". However, I forgot to remind you to add [Delimeters](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to the regex.  eg. `if (!preg_match("/(^\d{10}$|^\d{8}$|^\d[A-Za-z-]{13}$|^\d[A-Za-z]{11}$)/", $voucher))`.  You probably already know that, or figured that out.  Just sayin.  :)

Comment: Yes, i added them.  Thanks again for your assistance in this!  I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{10})?(\d{8})?(\d[a-zA-Z-]+)?`

This creates three optional groups, 1-3, that will capture any 10 digits (group 1), any 8 digits (group 2), or a number followed by alpha characters, with or without hyphens (group 3).

Here is a link to [the expression](http://regex101.com/r/bM6zL1) on regex101.

Comment: I think you would want to add start and end of string assertions (`^` and `$`). otherwise `hello1000150000` would actually be a match.

Comment: I don't disagree, but it's not clear what the requirement is so I left that out with the idea that it could be restricted if necessary.

Comment: Cool.  Just thought I'd mention.  :)

Comment: No worries at all. And I like seeing the different takes on the expressions too. Rick can use yours if he just needs one matching group or mine if wants to differentiate which of the three patterns were matched, and of course can add the anchors depending on what the input string looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/^[0-9](?:[0-9]{7}(?:[0-9]{2})?|[A-Z]*(?>-[A-Z]+)*)$/
```

The main interests of this pattern are:

- to avoid strings like this: `9ABCD-EFGH-` *(that finishs with an hyphen)*
- to not retry all the digits by making the 2 last digits optional. *(instead of using an alternation)*
- to try to match the first digit only once. *(the pattern fails immediatly if the first character is not a digit.)*

Comment: This is way too complicated.  Performance is not a legitimate concern, and there's no other reason to prefer this over the simple alternation suggested by [MElliott](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21920046/20938).  (The part about no trailing hyphens is probably valid, but that requirement wasn't mentioned in the question.)  Also, your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Thanks to point the unbalanced group. "too complicated" is only a fancy of the mind. Happy that you note that strings like "1------------------AAAAAAAAAAAAAA----------" are not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could use *alternation*.  That is, write the three regexs and string them together with the | sign meaning "Match one of this".

So

```
/[^...$]|\d|Z$/
```

(I.e.  three characters or contains a number or ends with Z.)